# Is there a benefit in eliminating the unique-ness of a redundant unique index on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indices

Whilst analyzing the database structure of a legacy application, I discovered in several tables there are 2 unique indices which both have the exact same columns, except in a different order.

Having 2 unique indices covering the same columns is clearly redundant, so my first instinct was to completely drop one of them. But then I thought some of the queries emmitted by the application might be making use of the index I might delete, so I thought to convert it instead into a regular index.

To the best of my knowledge, whenever a row is inserted/updated in a table having a unique index, SQL Server spends some milliseconds validating each unique index/constraint still holds true - so by converting one of these indices into a non-unique I hope processing of this table might be sped up a bit, please confirm or dispel.

On the other hand, I don't understand what's the benefit in having to unique indices covering the same columns on a table. Any ideas what this could be done for? Could something get lost if I convert one of them onto a regular one?

Comment: Unique indexes also help the optimizer better understand cardinality and sometimes generate a better plan as a result. If you change a unique index to non-unique, you may have some regression as a result.

Comment: @DanGuzman If you have 2 unique indices on the same tables with the exact same columns in each, that regression you mention cannot happen at all, ever.

Comment: but you said there were index hints, in which case you can have regression changing from unqique to non-unique.

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you please expand on that? Cause at first sight, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me: if I have a UNIQUE index on (columnA, columnB), and another unique index on (columnB, columnA), any and all combination of values in these 2 columns will always be unique, always, whether there's just one unique index on them or whether there are 2. If I change the 2nd index into a non-unique one, the values it points to will still be unique by virtue of the 1st index, it cannot be any other way

Comment: Right, but if you have a query hint using the non-unique version of the same index, SQL Server might choose a different plan using the index because it cannot ensure the values are unique.

Answer (score 2):

check the index usage stats to see if they are both being used.
[sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1239/how-to-get-index-usage-information-in-sql-server/)

If not, delete the unused index.

Generally speaking, indexes are used for filtering, then ordering.  It is possible that you may have queries that are needing to filter on the leading columns of both indexes.  If that is the case, you'll reduce how deep the query can be optimized by getting rid of one.  That may not be a big deal as it may still be able to satisfactorily use the remaining index.

For example, if I have 2 indexes with four columns:

## 1: Columns A, B, C, D

## 2: Columns A, B, D, C

Any query that currently prefers #2 could still gain benefits by using #1 if #2 is not available.  It would just limit the selectivity to column B rather than all the way down to column D.

If you're not sure, try disabling (not deleting) the less used index and see if you notice any problems.  If something slows down, it is simple enough to enable it again.

As always, try it in a non-production environment first.

UPDATE

---

Yes you can safely remove the uniqueness of one of the indexes.  It only needs to be enforced by one of them.  The only concern would be if the vendor decided to do the same and chooses the other index.

However, since this is from a vendor, I'd recommend you contact them if there are performance concerns.  If you're not running into a performance issue worth a support request to them, then just leave it alone.

Comment: I cannot disable nor delete any of the indices, as this application tends to use index hints with almost any query it emmits. I already tried deleting redundant indices and was hit by misterious errors in the front-end app, until a trace revealed the index-hints galore. As it was bought rather than developped in-house, I don't have the source code nor will I ever have it. Hence my question is limited to: can I safely make non-UNIQUE one of the indices? Is there a potential downside?

Comment: Well, the product "as-is" is pure garbage. It emits very inefficient queries, whose speed I've often increased just by changing the definition of the index they rely on with those damned index hints. It has redundant or sub-optimal indices in a lot of tables, has some tables that use 10x the size of data just for indices. It also alters the normal connection values to SQL S. so that SQL S. doesn't handle the race conditions itself. Result? Several times per week I see table blocks, which I have to resolve manually by killing one connection. Oh, also, it doesn't bother using transactions...